# save and load modifications with qsettings

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qpushbutton, qsettings

I have 2 windows ( window 1 ) & ( window 2 ) : see pictures.
-On window 1 there is an "edit" button that should open window 2 ( and load modifs saved on window 2 )
-On window 2, I have 96 buttons which are initially green, if I click on one it becomes red.
The "OK" button that I have should close window 2 and save the modifications ( red buttons ).
If I re-open window 2 by clicking on the "edit" button of window 1, the red buttons of the last step should stay red and become uncheckable.
 How can I do that with QSettings ?
This is my code of the savesettings method : ( I don't know if it is correct or not but I think yes !)

```
void Vessels::SaveSettings()
{
        QSettings setting("My_vessels","My_selected_vessels");
        setting.beginGroup("Vessels");
        if (ui->pushButton_4->isChecked()){
        ui->pushButton_4->setCheckable(false);}
        setting.setValue("selected",ui->pushButton_4->isCheckable());
        setting.endGroup();
}
```

I am facing 2 problems : 
1) The save and load buttons ( which are in this case respectively "OK" and "Edit" ) are not from the same window.
2) I don't know how to implement the loadSettings method that I should append to the "Edit" button.

[image]

Comment: I m a new qt user and I must finish the project in some days!

Comment: It looks you have created your 96 buttons by hand, not generated dynamically, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution, as I have come up with, please test on your side, its working for me:

[image: Solved screen-shot]

File: QSettings2.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-01-23T19:21:17
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QSettings2
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        dialog.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        dialog.h \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        dialog.ui \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

---

File: dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class QLabel;
class QSettings;
namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QSettings *settings, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButtonOK_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonCancel_clicked();

private:
    QLabel* CreateNewLabel(QString text, QWidget* parent);
    void saveSettings();
    void loadSettings();
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QSettings *m_settings;
    const int ROWS = 8, COLS = 12;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

---

File: mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QSettings;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSettings* m_settings;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

File: dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSettings>

Dialog::Dialog(QSettings *settings, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog),
    m_settings(settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->frame->setStyleSheet(QString());//we did draw border just for design time view
    ui->pushButton_Circular->hide();

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout();

    //gridLayout->setColumnStretch(0, 1);
    //gridLayout->setRowStretch(0, 1);

    for(int i = 1; i <= COLS; i++)
    {
        //gridLayout->setColumnStretch(i, 1);
        QLabel *label = CreateNewLabel(QString::number(i), this);
        gridLayout->addWidget(label, 0, i);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++)
    {
        //gridLayout->setRowStretch(i, 1);
        QLabel *label = CreateNewLabel(QString("%1").arg(static_cast<char>('A' + i -1)), this);
        gridLayout->addWidget(label, i, 0);
    }

    QString buttonIdText;
    for(int i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<= COLS; j++)
        {
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
            button->setMaximumSize(40, 40);
            button->setMinimumSize(40, 40);
            button->setStyleSheet(ui->pushButton_Circular->styleSheet());
            button->setCheckable(true);

            buttonIdText = QString::number((i-1)*COLS + j);
            button->setText(buttonIdText);
            button->setObjectName("GridButton_" + buttonIdText);

            gridLayout->addWidget(button, i, j);
        }
    }

    ui->frame->setLayout(gridLayout);
    loadSettings();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

QLabel *Dialog::CreateNewLabel(QString text, QWidget *parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(text, parent);
    label->setFont(QFont(label->font().family(), 10, 500));
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 0, 0);");
    label->setMaximumSize(40, 40);
    label->setMinimumSize(40, 40);
    return label;
}

void Dialog::saveSettings()
{
    QString key;
    QVariant value;
    m_settings->beginGroup("GridButtonsStatus");
    foreach(QObject *childObject, ui->frame->children())
    {
        if(QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(childObject))
        {
            key = button->objectName();
            value = button->isChecked();
            m_settings->setValue(key, value);
        }
    }
    m_settings->endGroup();
    m_settings->sync();
}

void Dialog::loadSettings()
{
    QString key;
    m_settings->beginGroup("GridButtonsStatus");
    for(int i = 1; i <= ROWS * COLS; i++)
    {
        key = QString("GridButton_%1").arg(i);
        qDebug() << "--- key = " << key <<", value = " <<  m_settings->value(key) << endl;
        QPushButton *button = ui->frame->findChild<QPushButton*>(key); //key was push button object name
        if(button)
        {
            bool is_Checked = m_settings->value(key, false).toBool();
            button->setChecked(is_Checked);
            button->setEnabled(!is_Checked);
        }
    }
    m_settings->endGroup();
}

void Dialog::on_pushButtonOK_clicked()
{
    saveSettings();
    close();
}

void Dialog::on_pushButtonCancel_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

---

File: main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

File: mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QSettings>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow), m_settings(new QSettings(qAppName() + ".ini", QSettings::IniFormat))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
#include <QDebug>
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog dialog(m_settings);
    dialog.exec();
}
```

---

File: dialog.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>730</width>
    <height>501</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>331</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Choose your vessels:</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButtonOK">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>560</x>
     <y>440</y>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>OK</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_Circular">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>440</y>
     <width>40</width>
     <height>40</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: outset;
    background: qradialgradient(
        cx: 0.3, cy: -0.4, fx: 0.3, fy: -0.4,
        radius: 1.35, stop: 0 green, stop: 1 #009900
        );
    padding: 5px;
    }

QPushButton:hover {
    background: qradialgradient(
        cx: 0.3, cy: -0.4, fx: 0.3, fy: -0.4,
         radius: 1.35, stop: 0 red, stop: 1 #004400
        );
    }

QPushButton:checked {
    border-style: inset;
    background: qradialgradient(
        cx: 0.4, cy: -0.1, fx: 0.4, fy: -0.1,
        radius: 1.35, stop: 0 red, stop: 1 #990000
        );
    }
</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="checked">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>520</width>
     <height>360</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>520</width>
     <height>360</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>520</width>
     <height>360</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">border:1px solid red</string>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButtonCancel">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>370</x>
     <y>440</y>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>CANCEL</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <zorder>frame</zorder>
  <zorder>label</zorder>
  <zorder>pushButtonOK</zorder>
  <zorder>pushButton_Circular</zorder>
  <zorder>pushButtonCancel</zorder>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

File: mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>573</width>
    <height>374</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>271</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Prepare YourSolutions</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>9</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Solution 1</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>154</x>
      <y>152</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Edit</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.
When I stop running the program I want to initilize the settings ( all buttons are green and checkable ).
I tried to create a global variable bool init(true).
and then in the dialog.cpp : if(!init) loadSettings;
And in the saveSettings I'll add init=false;
The prooblem is that I cannot this variable , I get always the following error : undefined reference to 'init'

Comment: In which file you have declared that init variable ?
Generally its bad idea to have global variable do it if there is no other way.
You should pass a variable from one function to another.
Also if you have to create global variable only then define that in a .cpp file not in .h 
 this will save you from multiple definition error if the .h is included in more than one file. But for the access-or to know that such variable is defined some where you should declare same variable as extern in the access-or  file.

Comment: I declare it extern bool init in a .h file .
I initialized it in a .cpp file ( init=true);
The problem is when I append a value ( 0 or 1 ) to init, then I get the error.
What can I do in this case ?
Is there another possibility to do that without a global variable ?

Comment: append ?? or assign ? you should show your code, if you can.
You can pass any variable to a public function(bool isInit); of dialog class or even in the constructor as I have passed settings variable.
`Dialog::Dialog(QSettings *settings, QWidget *parent) ` in that you can add one more bool isInit parameter after settings

Comment: Can you please modify the code that you have written, so that if I run the program for first time ( first click on Edit ) , all buttons are green ?

Comment: Or can you show me how to declare init as a global variable without getting the following error : undefined reference to 'init'.
Because the global variable will solve the problem.

Comment: That is already happening with the existing code on my PC.
All buttons are green on first run. And in subsequent runs also they are green only unless user clicks on any and then clicks OK, and you open dialog again either in same run or next run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206597/discussion-between-sumit-and-malek-samet).

Answer (score 0):

First, try to check your registry to check if you saved the values correctly.

Regarding the load function, you may use something like that:

```
QSettings settings("My_vessels","My_selected_vessels");
settings.beginGroup("Vessels");
checked = settings.value("selected").toBool();
settings.endGroup();
```

I'm sorry, but I don't know all your variables names. However, this is the same format of my function to load things from QSettings.

I hope it helps.